# Find all distinct values for particular field in index by using Elastic4s client

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic4s

How can I use elastic4s to get all distinct values for particular field?

Example in JSON:

```
GET persons/_search
{
 "size":"0",
 "aggs" : {
  "uniq_gender" : {
   "terms" : { "field" : "Gender" }
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

It looks like this:

```
    index: 'test',
    body: {
        "aggs": {
            "uniq_gender": {
                "terms": {"field": "Gender"}
            }
        }
    },
```

The response would look a little something like:

```
{
  "uniq_gender": {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": "male",
        "doc_count": 55
      },
      {
        "key": "female",
        "doc_count": 38
      },
      {
        "key": "other",
        "doc_count": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Important to note from the docs:

> terms aggregation should be a field of type keyword or any other data type suitable for bucket aggregations. In order to use it with text you will need to enable fielddata.

Meaning if your gender field is index'd as text you have to set fielddata to true on the mapping, find out how to do so [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html).

Comment: thank you. But the questions was - how can I do similar query by using elastic4s library

Comment: @smaiakov This [post](https://sksamuel.github.io/elastic4s/docs/search/search.html) might be useful to understand how to use terms aggregation in elastic4s DSL.

Comment: How to create tempalte using elastic4s from raw json haveing setting and mapping details.

Answer (score 0):

For elastic4s client, use [termsAgg(name: String, field: String)](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/3454148330eb86ee918c4ffd34b66f44f430f4cc/elastic4s-core/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/api/AggregationApi.scala#L109).

For your case, code looks like this:

```
search("persons")
      .size(0)
      .aggs(
        termsAgg("uniq_gender", "Gender")
      )
```